# How can I modify real time verbose output of a command in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If I run command `ping google.com`. It will give continuous output on the terminal.
Example output:

```
64 bytes from 74.125.130.101: icmp_seq=1 ttl=42 time=980 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.130.101: icmp_seq=2 ttl=42 time=1883 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.130.101: icmp_seq=3 ttl=42 time=1947 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.130.101: icmp_seq=4 ttl=42 time=1273 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.130.101: icmp_seq=5 ttl=42 time=848 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.130.101: icmp_seq=6 ttl=42 time=1072 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.130.101: icmp_seq=7 ttl=42 time=1202 ms
```

Now if I want to modify each output line to show only the `64 bytes from 74.125.130.101:` part, how can I do that?

I want to know a generic method which will work with other commands too which produce real time verbose output.

Comment: Just pipe to sed/awk/etc.?

Comment: i.e. `ping google.com | sed 's/:.*$//'` will give you the output you request. Making such a thing generic means (IMHO) to do some analysis and establish a list of verbs you want to apply to output. For this case, you could make a function `right_rm` (remove from the right) side, but you'd still need to pass in `:.*` as an argument. In *nix-land, this is consider contrary to the standard of "use pipes to whittle down output to get what you need" and not worth the effort ;-) (sorry). Feel free to expand your defintion of generic and we may have some ideas to help . Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cut` through a pipe:

```
ping google.com | cut -d":" -f1
```

Answer (score 2):

awk-way:

```
ping google.com | awk -F ":" '{print $1}'
```

if you need trailing colons exactly like in the question:

```
ping google.com | awk -F ":" '{print $1 ":"}'
```

grep-way:

```
ping google.com | grep -o "^.*:"
```

sed-way:

```
ping google.com | sed  's/\(.*:\).*/\1/'
```